# Vue.js recalculate computed properties on client after server rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've got this simple vue single file component

```
<template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <v-card v-bind:color="color" class="white--text">
          <v-card-title primary-title>
            <div>
              <h3 class="headline mb-0">Kangaroo Valley Safari</h3>
              <div>{{card_text}}</div>
            </div>
          </v-card-title>
        </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
import MessageCard from '../components/MessageCard.vue';
const colors = [
  'red',
  'pink',
  'purple',
  'indigo',
  'green'
];

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      card_text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, brute iriure accusata ne mea. Eos suavitate referrentur ad, te duo agam libris qualisque, utroque quaestio accommodare no qui.'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    color: function () {
      const length = colors.length;
      return colors[Math.round(-0.5 + Math.random() * (length + 1))] + ' darken-3';
    }
  },
  components: {
    MessageCard
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that by server-side render I am getting computed `color` of `v-card` as a style, but when the client side hydration starts computed property recalculates which changes the style and causes rerender.

Of cause, I can fix it fix  tag, but I'm curious is there some other ways to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Computed properties are always reevaluated during client side hydration. It is generally not a good idea to relay on side effects in your computeds (like `Math.random()`), since Vue.js expects computed properties to be [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).
So usually you would calculate that random value once at creation and store it as `data`. However the `data` of a component is also not preserved between SSR and hydration.

So a way you could solve this, would be by storing the random value in the state of a Vuex store. It is then possible to [restore the state](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/data.html#final-state-injection) of the store form the server in the client.